# php error: Indirect modification of overloaded property class::$data has no effect

Tags: php, get, set, opencart, opencart-module

I have this sample code from my default function of the controller class.

```
$this->data['heading_title']= $this->language->get('heading_title');

$this->data['text_enabled'] = $this->language->get('text_enabled');
```

when i run the code it just keeps on giving me this error

> Indirect modification of overloaded property
>   ControllerModuleHelloworld::$data has no effect in /the/path/of/the/file

When looking at some of the previous answers here, it seems that mostly is about calling by reference. but whenever I try it using this code

```
&_set( $this->data['heading_title'], $this->language->get('heading_title') );
```

it returns this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&' in /the/path/of/the/file.php on line 23

Can you please assist me in order to know what's wrong and how to fix the bug.

Comment: Wherever you think you found that code, you misread it. I suppose `data` is a non-public property of the `ControllerModuleHelloworld` class. You need to make the magic getter return it by reference.